# Blender is running too slow

Tags: windows, installation

First it longs about 20 min only showing the terminal window.
Then when blender starts, if i want to import a file, or save a file, it lasts another ~20 mins showing "blender (no responde)"(Blender is not responding) before doing what I asked.

My OS is Windows 7 (64 bit) and i'm running Blender in Spanish. I first downloaded the installer and installed it, then uninstalled and then downloaded the ZIP version. In both versions the result is the same.

Not long ago since I format the pc. And when i first installed Blender (about a month ago) it ran ok.

This monday was the first time i noticed that behavior...

(sorry for my english :) )

Comment: try to use the task manager to see if, when this happens, another process is using most of the available cpu so that Blender is so much slow. It could be an antivirus, or a svchost process doing something like updates in the background. How many cores have your cpu (see performance tab in task manager), and are they all 100% because of which process?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about how to use Blender but about figuring out why Blender is running slowly (Often this has nothing to do with Blender but the OS or some other program.

Answer (score 0):

8 cores (4+4HT). No antivirus installed.
No process that consumes more than 1% of the CPU.
The CPU is at 1%-7% of use.
Anyway, now i think this is not Blender's failure because now Firefox ( ^^U ) is doing something like that.
I'm going to reinstall Windows today.
Thank you anyway.

(sorry for my english again)

Comment: good luck @BATIS !